# Smarty templates for static sites

Tags: php, smarty

I've been looking over the examples for Smarty Templates but can't find my answer.

Currently, I have a fairly simple 10 page static HTML website.
I'm considering using Smarty to reduce the obvious HTML duplication (header, footer etc...)

Is this possible using Smarty Templates? Or am I better off using simple php includes?

Comment: You can't find the answer? Really? It's probably the most obvious thing smarty has...

Comment: If you need just includes of static HTML code - I don't think that there is the reason to use Smarty here. It is great template engine but you will have additional loading of your webserver resources.

Comment: @nile i couldn't find a ultra simple example.

Comment: @RomanS may have just answered my question / confirmed my suspicion

Comment: @alexjamesbrown by reading the first few pages of the documentation, the intent becomes pretty clear. its not that hard to just dive into. try creating 1 page using a tempate like smarty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this using Smarty Templates. However, if you're just trying to include header/footer/menu templates and really don't need other features Smarty has to offer, it's probably better to just steer clear of it. Are you asking *how* to do it in Smarty, or which is better? If the latter, it's probably better in your situation to use include.

```
<?php
$inc = array(
    "title" => "About",
    "active" => "About"
);

include_once("inc/header.php");
?>

<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>

<?php
include_once("inc/footer.php");
?>
```

While in Smarty, you'd do something like this:

```
<?php
require_once('Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->display("inc/header.tpl");
$smarty->display("inc/about.tpl");
$smarty->display("inc/footer.tpl");
```

If you're lacking some features Smarty may offer and feel that you want them, it may be better just to create an extremely simple templating system class by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Smarty. Just use PHP.

`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/header.php');`